# Elastic search doesn't index new mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

My problem is with Elasticasearch, I have 1564 indexes and 1564 documents in MongoDB (after my last populating operation : in Symfony with Elasticabundle :`php app/console foqs:elastica:populate`)
but when I add a document manually the number of indexes remains 1564 where it should be 1565
Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality to update Elasticsearch indexes when Doctrine entities are modified is documented in the README file under [Realtime, selective index update](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle#realtime-selective-index-update). The configuration option is `listeners`, which falls under the `persistence` option you should already have defined per model.

Comment: Yes you are right ! it's the listeners , but it does just for single inserts, I'm using scrapy and I insert 10 documents at once , how can I cure that ?

Comment: Isn't [scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy) a Python project? If that's what you're using, I don't see why you'd expect it to work with FOSElasticaBundle's listeners. If you are doing these insertions via Doctrine MongoDB ODM, can you share some code? Keep in mind that these listeners will only operate if you create your models, persist them, and flush the DocumentManager. Manual inserts through something like the query builder or the collection's `batchInsert()` method are not going to trigger lifecycle events.

Comment: Yes I think you are right , I thought ElasticaBundle uses a river that listens all the time to any action on the database.

Comment: [elasticsearch-river-mongodb](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) may be just what you're looking for. Additionally, there is the [mongo-connector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector) project (introduced in [this blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector)), which aims to keep MongoDB and ElasticSearch in sync, although I don't believe it uses the River API.